# Fiori - Cross Application Navigation

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to navigate between the applications in launchpad. I have found with lot of searching that, through CrossApplicationNavigation in ushell is the way. Here is the link to documentation (SAPUI5 SDK - Demo Kit)

Each application in launchpad has 'semantic object' and 'action' for further navigation.

I have followed documentation and written following piece of code to create CrossApplicaionNavigation service.

```
var fgetService =sap.ushell && sap.ushell.Container && sap.ushell.Container.getService;
this.oCrossAppNavigator = fgetService && fgetService("CrossApplicationNavigation");
```

Just to make sure that oCrossAppNavigator service is properly initiate wrote following code.

```
var hashForApp =  this.oCrossAppNavigator.hrefForExternal({
            rget : { semanticObject : "SalesOrder",action : "create" }
});
console.log("Hash for the application: " + hashForApp);

console Output: #SalesOrder-create
```

So knowing the service works, I wrote following code to navigate to the "SalesOrder" application and to the "create" action.

```
this.oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
    target : { semanticObject : "SalesOrder",action : "create" }
});
```

Here is the my issue. Above statement neither goes to the SalesOrder application nor prints any error in the console.
It supposed to update the URL with the above hash code and go to that application.

Note: Manual changing of URL with the above hash code correctly going to SalesOrder application.

Thanks in advance,

vagley

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run this locally? Because if so, then it doesn't work as expected, unless both the applications (the app where you've added the cross app code **and** the 'SalesOrder-create' app) are running in the "[local sandbox](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/89/6efc419d994463a7c148b6904760a8/content.htm)"

However if you have tried to run this piece of code in an app installed in a *Fiori Launchpad* on an SAP dev/test system, which **also** has the 'SalesOrder-create' app in the same launchpad, then it should work just fine.

Also use the following way to check if the cross-app service is working, because it looks like your code always outputs `#SalesOrder-create`

```
if (sap.ushell && sap.ushell.Container && sap.ushell.Container.getService)
{
  var oCrossAppNavigator = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");

   oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
                      target: { semanticObject : "SalesOrder", action: "create" },   //the app you're navigating to 
                        // params : { param1:data, param2:data}
                     }); 
  }
else
{
     jQuery.sap.log.info("Cannot Navigate - Application Running Standalone");
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not running locally and both applications are configured in the same launchpad. I followed your way still neither print anything in the console nor navigate to desire app. Looking forward your reply.

Comment: Interesting. It's difficult to take a guess now why that's happening, if there is no response. There's one thing you can try, can you use the navigation code in the 'SalesOrder' app itself and try to navigate _into_ the app you are now trying from, by providing the right 'semanticObject' and 'action'. Doesn't solve your problem, but if it works, then you can confirm that atleast the navigation is working