# SAPUI5 - Open new app through component.js

Tags: javascript, components, sapui5, sage-erp

I'm developing a type of Launchpad do Fiori but using data from Sage X3. 
Do you know if it's possible have 2 local aplications where one calls another through Component.js ?

Can you help me with this ?

Best Regards

Comment: whats your trying code?

Comment: I'm looking, but I can't find anything. So I wanted to know if it's possible to do it or not. The only code I have is to mimic the launchpad

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following SO question [Fiori - Cross Application Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844715/fiori-cross-application-navigation) and this SCN blog [Cross Application Navigation between SAPUI5 applications](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/20/cross-application-navigation-between-sapui5-applications/).

In a nutshell, you must run the app(s) inside either the "real" Fiori Launchpad or you must run both of them in the local Fiori sandbox (if you are using WebIDE). Then you can navigate from one to another using the [CrossApplicationNavigation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.services.CrossApplicationNavigation.html) service to go from one to another using the *semantic objects* of the apps. Something along the lines:

```js
// You should also check if the sap.ushell.Container exists before this
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").toExternal({
    target: { 
        semanticObject: "Your target object", 
        action: "The action for the object" 
    }, 
});
```

To get your WebIDE test environment, you should look at this documentation: [Testing Multiple SAP Fiori Applications](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?1114b927f5bc417e9a5912be40ee9ab8.html).

Comment: I don't have a semantic obect because I'm adapt Fiori app to other the data base system. 
So in the launchpad,  I created a simple page, where the user do the login and then appears two tiles for two diferents pages. When in this case I only want access locally two diferrents pages that I have in sames page. I can use your propose ?